# Dynamically added options to selectbox do not delete

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to quite figure this out.

My functions work as they should however, there is one discrepancy, when the option values are added dynamically from the input box, and I hit the delete key in the [list1] , they do not get removed. However, if the option values are added statically, then they delete just fine as they should. Any ideas?

I am really scratching my head with this one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function add_refdoc() {

    var x = document.getElementById("list1");

    var option = document.createElement("option");

    var input = document.getElementById('refdocs_input')

    option.text = input.value

    x.add(option,x.option)

    x.selectedIndex = x.options.length - 1;
}


function del_refdoc(e) {
    var evt = e ? e : event;
    var sel = evt.target ? evt.target : evt.srcElement;
    if(evt.keyCode && evt.keyCode == 46 || evt.which == 46) {
        var val = sel.value;
        var opts = sel.getElementsByTagName("option");
        if(val != "") {
            for(var i=0; i<opts.length; i++) {
                if(val == opts[i].value)
                    sel.removeChild(opts[i]);
                }
        }
    }
}

</script>


</head>

<body>
<input id="refdocs_input" type="text"/>

<input value="add" type="button" onclick="add_refdoc()"/>

<br>
<select onkeydown="del_refdoc(event)" style="width: 250px;" id="list1"></select>

<br><br>

<select onkeydown="del_refdoc(event)" style="width: 250px;" id="list2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add some `console.log` in the way to check your variables states...

Comment: Might be due to using `<select>`'s `.add` and not _HTMLElement's_ `.appendChild`

Comment: It seems to delete fine when you hit the key on the input but not on the drop down.  see http://jsfiddle.net/FLRD6/

Comment: @davy if that is true, the _target_ is probably not the `<select>` as assumed in code.

Comment: It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/85jr2/

Comment: @Paul - sorry - yes had already started comment and then got distracted :)

Comment: I re-wrote it in a way (I think) cleaner and it works the same http://jsfiddle.net/qy3Wq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was the way the options values were being added

So I changed this code and it worked.

```
function add_refdoc() {

    var s = document.getElementById('list1')

    var t = document.getElementById('input1').value

    s.options[s.options.length] = new Option(t, t)

}
```